# XSLT: Grouping issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a flat XML file that is coming from a client.  I need to group the data on node pattern matching.

For example, I need to convert this-

```
<root>
<p>
    <row>
        <head>Heading 1</head>
    </row>
</p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
<p>
    <row>
        <head>Heading 2</head>
    </row> 
</p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
<p>
    <row>
        <head>Heading 3</head>
    </row> </p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
<p>Some Text</p> 
</root>
```

My requirements is: 
Grouping by pattern `<P><row><head>` (where no text) and add separate section to each matching group.

```
Expected output would be :
<root>
<Mygroup>
    <p>
        <row>
            <head>Heading 1</head>
        </row>
    </p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
</Mygroup>
<Mygroup>
    <p>
        <row>
            <head>Heading 2</head>
        </row> 
    </p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
</Mygroup>
<Mygroup>
    <p>
        <row>
            <head>Heading 3</head>
        </row> </p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
    <p>Some Text</p> 
</Mygroup>
</root>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Look at any `xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with` example (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples) if you can use XSLT 2.0

Comment: You really need to tag XSLT questions as xslt 1.0 or 2.0, especially for grouping problems where the solutions will be radically different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-starting-with=".[row/head]">
        <Mygroup>
          <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </Mygroup>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

`for-each-group` selects all `p` elements (the entire content of the `root`),
dividing them into groups.

Each group begins from a `p` element (which for `group-starting-with`
is the current element `.`)), meeting the predicate:
must have a child `row` with a `head` inside.

And now move on to the output: The content of each group is enclosed with
`Mygroup` opening and closing tags.
And between them there is the content of the whole current group.

Note that I used `sequence` not `copy-of`.
I did it for efficiency reasons (search the web for differences between
them).

Comment: Thanks for the help Valdi_Bo. it worked.. I really appreciate the explanation on how it works.